# How does the energy of a solar flare propagate?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, plasma-physics, sun, solar-wind, stellar-dynamics

Does it radiate outward, spherically, or is it more directed? Is there some opening angle? Is it more complex than this?

Answer (score 0):

It is very complicated because a solar flare is a chaotic instability in the solar plasma.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/239612)

Comment: I think this answered the OP’s final question “Is it more complex than this?” The fact that it is makes the prior questions moot; I don’t think they have answers. However, if they do, I look forward to a better answer from someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Since the original definition of a [solar flare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_flare) only depended upon an increase in x-ray flux in a small spatial region on the sun<sup>1</sup>, the energy of a solar flare would then propagate in the form of electromagnetic radiation.

However, our current understanding would require that we include the beaming of ions and electrons by the processes ultimately responsible for all of this (i.e., [magnetic reconnection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_reconnection)) that are sent both into the [interplanetary medium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interplanetary_medium) and toward the surface of the sun, i.e., kinetic energy flux.  Most of the electron energy kept near the sun is converted to x-rays through thin and thick target [bremsstrahlung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung) radiation.  The trapped accelerated ions are more difficult to detect as the conversion to electromagnetic radiation is not as efficient and these tend to cause nuclear reactions producing gamma rays.

**Footnotes**

1. Well, the first observations were of only white light flares, which tend to be the strongest flares for numerous reasons.