# Other than magnitude what are the differences between CME's and Solar flares?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, astrophysics, plasma-physics, sun, solar-wind

I could not understand the differences between a CME and a Solar flare, aside from the fact that they differ in magnitude.

Comment: You could check out https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/87/ . Major differences are in composition, magnitude and effects on earth.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/258093/59023 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/445355/59023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [solar flare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_flare) is just an enhancement of electromagnetic radiation in the UV to $\gamma$-ray range (mostly UV and x-rays).  A [coronal mass ejection (CME)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronal_mass_ejection) is a large eruption or ejection of [plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)) from the [solar corona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona) and upper [chromosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromosphere).  That is, the former is defined by the intensification of massless photons in the UV to $\gamma$-ray range while the latter is defined by the physical release of about a billion tons of [plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)).

You may find the following helpful as well:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/258093/59023 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/149199/59023 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/549420/59023.