# Are solar flares and solar winds the same?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, astrophysics, plasma-physics, sun, solar-wind

A solar flare contains high energy protons and particles.

A solar wind is a stream of energized & charged particles primarily electrons & protons.

I am confused whether both are same or not? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> A solar flare contains high energy protons and particles.

No, not really.  A [solar flare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_flare) is just a localized enhancement of UV and x-ray radiation.  The processes that lead to a solar flare can, yes, accelerate particles both toward and away from the sun.  Those that impact the [chromosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromosphere) and [photosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosphere) can generate x-rays and $\gamma$-rays from [Bremsstrahlung radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung) and nuclear processes, respectively.

> A solar wind is a stream of energized & charged particles primarily electrons & protons.

Kind of, yes.  The [solar wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_wind) is more just a supersonic wind resulting from some imbalanced forces near the sun (the source of the acceleration is still under debate) causing a steady stream of particles leaving the [solar corona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona).  The particles that escape the solar atmosphere need not be energized beyond thermal energies in the sense your comment seems to imply.  That is, they have a bulk flow speed on the order of ~400 km/s but temperatures of only ~10 eV by the time they reach Earth (several 10s of eV closer to the sun).  For protons, the [thermal speed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/179057/59023) (typically ~25-50 km/s near Earth) is much lower than the bulk flow speed.  For electrons, it's the opposite as their mass is ~1836 times smaller than the proton's (typically >1500 km/s near Earth).

> I am confused whether both are same or not?

No, the solar wind and solar flares are not the same phenomena.  As I said above, a solar flare is just an enhancement of electromagnetic radiation in the UV to $\gamma$-ray range (mostly UV and x-rays).  The solar wind is the constant flow of thermal particles from the sun's upper atmosphere.

You may find the following useful as well:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/258093/59023 or https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/149199/59023 or https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/391589/59023 or https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/445355/59023.

Answer (score 0):

A solar flare is an explosion of plasma caused by the twisting, crossing, or re-oraniztion of magnetic field lines near a sunspot.

The solar wind is caused by the outward expansion of plasma in the Sun's corona - or outer atmosphere.

The temperature of the corona is roughly $1$ million degrees $K$- it is so hot it can escape the gravity of the Sun.

The temperature of Sun's surface is roughly $6,000$ degrees $K.$